# How to sort a List of ArrayLists (not arrays)?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have an adjacency list implemented using a List[] of ArrayLists. I want to sort the List in descending order of the size of the ArrayLists. I figured I would do this by writing a Comparator... But how would I do this? or is this just not possible and I should do it another way?

```
Collections.sort(adjacency, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>()>() {
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> p1, ArrayList<Integer> p2) {
        return Integer.compare(p1.length, p2.length);
    }
});
```

The code on top is not functioning. I tried with just an ArrayList, List[], List as a Comparator type. Is there a wrapper class for list? Sorry if this may sound uneducated.

This is how I made the adjacency list:

```
List<Integer>[] adjacency;
adjacency = (List<Integer>[]) new List[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    adjacency[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `p1.length` be `p1.size()`? So you have an array of `ArrayList`s and you're trying to use `Collections.sort` to sort the array...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The code on top is not functioning.*

The code is not working because p1 and p2 are ArrayLists and they dont have a field named length, they have the method `size()`, that is what you need.

```
return Integer.compare(p1.size(), p2.size());
```

Comment: I'd be seriously careful before you answer this, and have a REALLY close look at how they are creating `adjacency` ;)